# Spring Security .DaoAuthenticationProvider: Cannot resolve reference to bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing Spring Security in project. I have reached an impasse stuck here since hours.

I am getting this error

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'UserDAOImpl' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'myUserDetailService' is defined
```

The project setup is very simple

spring-security.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailService">
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.com,app.com.controller,app.com.dao,app.com.service,app.com.model"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
            p:basename="messages"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

ApplicationContext.xml

```
  <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- <context:property-placeholder> XML element automatically registers a new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer 
    bean in the Spring Context. -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/> 

    <!-- Creating DataSource -->
      <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
      </bean>

    <!-- To persist the object to database, the instance of SessionFactory interface is created. 
SessionFactory is a singleton instance which implements Factory design pattern. 
SessionFactory loads hibernate.cfg.xml and with the help of TransactionFactory and ConnectionProvider 
implements all the configuration settings on a database. -->

<!-- Configuring SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>app.com.model.User</value>
                <value>app.com.model.Roles</value>
                <value>app.com.BaseEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Configuring Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

CustomUserDetailsService.java

```
@Service("myUserDetailService")
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    /*@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I also tried declaring the bean in both dispatcher-servlet.xml & application-context.xml it doesn't work

checked the context-component base package. It is scanning all the other classes present just fine. When I remove myUserDetailService from authentication provider the server starts just fine without any error.

I am really tired. Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew... got it working.

Moved

```
<context:component-scan base-package="app.com,app.com.controller,app.com.dao,app.com.service,app.com.model"/>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
            p:basename="messages"/>
```

from dispatcher-servlet to application-context.xml

Would anyone care to tell why it started working?

Answer (score 1):

the reason why you got this working after moving the definitions to your context file is because in spring, the definitions inside the dispatcher servlet are only visible to mvc, and definitions inside context are global (to servlet and security), here is a page where its clearly explained https://weblogs.java.net/blog/sgdev-blog/archive/2014/07/05/common-mistakes-when-using-spring-mvc